# Yom Kippur in the days of David's tent

Tags: word-study, leviticus, 2-samuel

How was the Yom Kippur ritual performed in the days of King David's tabernacle? Zadock was the high priest in Gibeon, and Abiathar in David's tent. How and where  was it performed , when the high priest should enter the Holy of Holies and make the annual propitiation for the sins of the people? For sure it couldn't be in Gibeon, once the Ark wasn't there...But how would it work then?

Comment: Welcome to BH. Please see the Tour and Help. Questions on BH need to be specific to the text of scripture. 'Topics' are 'off-topic'. Can you rephrase your question so that it is an investigation of text, rather than a discussion of topic ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately, this post is too far-ranging. Please narrow it down to a specific scripture so it will yield a definite answer. As it stands, it looks like it is seeking a conversation or discussion rather than an answer. We are different than other sites in this regard.